# How do i build a mysql stored procedure to join one out of two tables based on different conditions

Tags: mysql, loops, join, stored-procedures, call

So let's say i have three tables

1)User
2)Employee
3)Client

user holds basic data of whether employee or client and has a column that mentions if that user is employee or client

I want to achieve fetching the users and joining each user to his corresponding table.

For example,if i fetch a user who is an employee, it should join that user to employee table. Likewise for client.

Answer (score 1):

You could join to both in one query, with conditions in the JOIN clause for each:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
BEGIN
  SELECT ...
  FROM user AS u
  LEFT OUTER JOIN employee AS e
    ON u.id = e.user_id AND u.type='employee' 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN client AS c
    ON u.id = c.user_id AND u.type='client'; 
END
```

The user type can only have one value on a given row, so it may match employee or client, but it cannot match both. The one it doesn't match will return NULLs (that's how outer joins work).

---

Another strategy would be to use a [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(IN in_userid INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE user_type VARCHAR(10);

  SELECT type INTO user_type FROM user WHERE id = in_userid;

  CASE user_type
  WHEN 'employee' THEN
    SELECT ... FROM employee WHERE user_id = in_userid;
  WHEN 'client' THEN
    SELECT ... FROM client WHERE user_id = in_userid;
  ELSE
    -- should never happen
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = CONCAT('unknown user type', QUOTE(user_type));
  END;
END
```

Comment: But what if i do not want to use too many joins, i just want to select first, then loop and join still inside the procedure.How do i achieve this. Because i feel the type of users will grow in future so it wont just be employees and clients.

Comment: Perfect this is exactly it except for one thing. 
For this line of code

  SELECT type INTO user_type FROM user WHERE id = in_userid;

I want to loop through the user table, not select just one user id.
Could you update please?

Comment: No, that would require a cursor, which would be a lot more code. I suggest using the JOIN solution I showed first. It's simpler.

Comment: Thanks man, my concern is that there would be various user types in fututre and the joins will keep increasing

Comment: I recommend to cross that bridge when you come to it.